# Singular points of projective hypersurface and Veronese map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity, transversality, projective-varieties

Let $S = \{f = 0\} \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a hypersurface of degree $d$. Then $S$ is the intersection of $v(\mathbb{P}^n)$ with a unique hyperplane $H \subset \mathbb{P}^N$, where $v: \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^N$ is the Veronese morphism of degree $d$.

Lamotke writes in *The topology of complex varieties after S. Lefschetz*, that the regular (he calls them *simple*, but I think they are the same) points of $S$ are those points, where $H$ and $\mathbb{P}^n$ intersect transversally. Why is that the case? Or are simple points another thing than regular points?

Comment: If you have a (complex) smooth projective variety $X$ and two smooth projective subvarieties $Y_1$, $Y_2$ in $X$, then $Y_1 \cap Y_2$ is regular (or smooth) at a point $x$ if and only if $T_x Y_1 + T_x Y_2 = T_x X$, that is, if they *intersect transversally* at that point.

Comment: @Parthiv I don't think this is true: consider the curves $\{x=0,y^2-z=0\}$ and $\{y=0,z=0\}$ in $\mathbb{A}^3$. Their (scheme theoretic) intersection is the reduced point $(0,0,0)$, which is regular, but the tangent spaces of two curves can never span the tangent space of $\mathbb{A}^3$ for dimension reasons. Do we need some hypothesis about the dimensions of the subvariety?

Comment: Yes. Sorry! If $X$ is smooth of dimension $d$, and $Y_1$, $Y_2$ are smooth of codimension $d_1,d_2$ respectively. Then $Y_1 \cap Y_2$ is smooth of codimension $d_1 + d_2$ if and only if $\dots$

Comment: @ParthivBasu Thanks, I expanded on this in my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Parthiv Basu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/688651/parthiv-basu) mentioned in the comments, the following is true:

> Let $Y_1, Y_2 \subset X$ be smooth varieties, and let $x \in Y_1 \cap Y_2$ be a closed point, such that $\dim Y_1 \cap Y_2 = \dim Y_1 + \dim Y_2 - \dim X$, at $x$. Then $x$ is a regular point in the intersection if and only if $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ intersect transversally at $x$.

This is helpful, because the dimension requirement is always given if $Y_1$ is the image of the Veronese map, and $Y_2$ is a hyperplane, as no hyperplane contains $Y_1$.

*Proof*:

First observe the equality $$T_x(Y_1 \cap Y_2) = T_x Y_1 \cap T_x Y_2 \subset T_x X.$$ This is true for arbitrary varieties, smooth or not, if $T_x X, \ldots$ are the Zariski tangent spaces. Thus we have the inequality
$$\dim(T_x Y_1 \cap T_x Y_2) \geq \dim(Y_1 \cap Y_2) = \dim Y_1 + \dim Y_2 - \dim X = \dim T_x Y_1 +  \dim T_x Y_2 - \dim T_x X.$$
So we see that $T_x Y_1 + T_x Y_2 = T_x X$ if and only if we have "$=$" here, which is exactly the criterion for smoothness of $x$ in $Y_1 \cap Y_2$.